# Multiple function calls for parallel processing inside a loop

Tags: multiprocessing, runtime-error, python-multiprocessing

I wish to detect an image from my webcam and write the result whether it is moving left or right to a file. To increase the frame rate(because this project involves a lot more processing and might be run on a raspberry pi) I decided to do the file writing part through multiprocessing (which I am new to):

code:

### function for multi-processing

```
def send_cmd(cv):
    # ####EXECUTE LOGIC AND CREATE COMMAND###
# writing to file
# just a sample command// change as will
dictionary = {'left': 0, 'right': 0, 'stop': 0}

        if cv[0] == 'left':
            dictionary['right'] = 1
        else:
            dictionary['left'] = 1

cmd = '{"left":' + str(dictionary['left']) + ',"right":' + str(dictionary['left'
        ]) + ',"stop":' + str(dictionary['left']) + '}'
print("command written: " + cmd)
f = open('command.txt', 'w')
f.write(cmd)
f.close()
```

### Main code:

```
while True:
    try:
        frame = cv.VideoCapture(0)
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    if W is None or H is None:
        (H, W) = frame.shape[:2]

    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(cv.resize(frame, (300, 300)),
                                0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    rects = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):

        if detections[0, 0, i, 2] > args['confidence']:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([W, H, W, H])
            rects.append(box.astype('int'))

            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype('int')
            cv.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0,
                         0xFF, 0), 2)

    objects = ct.update(rects)

    for (objectID, centroid) in objects.items():

        text = 'ID {}'.format(objectID)
        cv.putText(
            frame,
            text,
            (centroid[0] - 10, centroid[1] - 10),
            cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.5,
            (0, 0xFF, 0),
            2,
            )
        cv.circle(frame, (centroid[0], centroid[1]), 4, (0, 0xFF,
                  0), -1)
        center = (centroid[0], centroid[1])
        pts.appendleft(center)

        for i in np.arange(1, len(pts)):

            if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                continue

            if counter >= 10 and i == 1 and pts[-1] is not None:
                dX = pts[-1][0] - pts[i][0]
                dY = pts[-1][1] - pts[i][1]
                global dirX
                global dirY
                (dirX, dirY) = ('', '')

                if np.abs(dX) > 20:
                    dirX = ('left' if np.sign(dX) == 1 else 'right')

                if np.abs(dY) > 20:
                    dirY = ('up' if np.sign(dY) == 1 else 'down')

                #tried multiprocessing with process method but to many process calls at the same time
                order = multiprocessing.Process(target = send_cmd,args = ([dirX, dirY]))
                order.start()
                order.join()

                # send_cmd(cv=[dirX, dirY], us=ultra_sonic)


                if dirX != '' and dirY != '':
                    direction = '{}-{}'.format(dirY, dirX)
                else:

                    direction = (dirX if dirX != '' else dirY)

            thickness = int(np.sqrt(args['buffer'] / float(i + 1))
                            * 2.5)

        cv.putText(
            frame,
            direction,
            (10, 30),
            cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.65,
            (0, 0, 0xFF),
            3,
            )
        cv.putText(
            frame,
            'dx: {}, dy: {}'.format(dX, dY),
            (10, frame.shape[0] - 10),
            cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            0.35,
            (0, 0, 0xFF),
            1,
            )

    cv.imshow('Frame', frame)
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    counter += 1
```

### Error:

```
 RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Can someone guide me?

Comment: Since you're new to multiprocessing, I would like to suggest that you first get this working in a single process. Once you have a working program, use this as a way to learn muktiprocessing. By doing this, you will know if the bug any bugs are due to the image processing or the threading.

Comment: I have got a working code for my whole project but the frame rate is around 0.5 fps (Which is very very slow). Hence I thought of this alternative. I have only mentioned the part of the code that is required for this query. I am sorry if I could not make myself clear. Can you help me with this??